# How to pass a variable from java file to a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable from java code to batch file.
The content of the batch file is-

```
@echo off 

set rootFolder=%1

set logFolder_Dir=logs

set outputLogsFolder_LocalDir=%rootFolder%\%logFolder_Dir%

set filename=%2

adb shell setprop persist.log.tag V

adb logcat com.harman.prometheusnav > %filename%.txt

pause
```

I need to pass the value of rootFolder and filename from java code to batch file.
Java code to run and close the batch file is -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "logs.bat");
    File dir = new File("C:\\WORKPLACE\\NavSDK\\Prometheus\\Automation\\promta\\src\\test\\resources");
    pb.directory(dir);
    Process p = pb.start();
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("taskkill /F /IM adb.exe /T");
```

Is there any other idea to update the batch variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)  for ProcessBuilder, you should simply just add your arguments to the end of the list.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "logs.bat", "C:\RootFoolder", "FileName");
    File dir = new File("C:\\WORKPLACE\\NavSDK\\Prometheus\\Automation\\promta\\src\\test\\resources");
    pb.directory(dir);
    Process p = pb.start();
```